# ng-submit won't work with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, turbolinks, ngresource

I have a Rails app using Angular and ngResource to display the content of my "Order" model. Inside the Angular part of the app, I can add and delete objects and it works fine. Only if I navigate to the page through my website (using turbolinks) the "addOrder()" function won't work. The deleteOrder() function and all the rest works, though. I checked what's going on with several console.logs and test functions and discovered that only ng-submit doesn't seem to trigger the function.

This is what the essential parts of my code look like:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('shop', ['ngResource']);

$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['shop'])
});

app.factory('models', ['$resource', function($resource){
  ...
}]);

app.controller('OrdersCtrl', ['$scope', 'models', function($scope, models){

  ...

  $scope.addOrder = function(){
    // doesn't work
    ...
  };

  $scope.deleteOrder = function(order){
    // works
    ...
  };

}])
```

**index.html.erb**

```
...

<form ng-submit="addOrder()">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="newOrder.total" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model="newOrder.product_id" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
  <?td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
  </td>
  </tr>
</form>

...

<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:'-id':reverse">
  {{order.id}}
  <button ng-click="deleteOrder(order)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</tr>

...
```

The fact that confuses me the most is, that seemingly only ng-submit doesn't work - but all the rest does.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

So I did some more research and finally figured out that the problem had nothing to do with turbolinks, Angular or Rails. The problem was, that I couldn't have a form **inside** a table. That caused the DOM to generate a `form` closing tag right after the opening tag with none of the inputs inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

So I did some more research and finally figured out that the problem had nothing to do with turbolinks, Angular or Rails. The problem was, that I couldn't have a form **inside** a table. That caused the DOM to generate a `form` closing tag right after the opening tag with none of the inputs inside.

So this code:

```
<form ng-submit="addOrder()">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="newOrder.total" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model="newOrder.product_id" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
  <?td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
  </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

would look like this in the DOM:

```
<form ng-submit="addOrder()"></form>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" step="0.01" ng-model="newOrder.total" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td>
    <select ng-model="newOrder.product_id" class="form-control">
      <option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
  <?td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try defining something like `page:change` as I guess that is the only part where turbolinks is not working.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load page:change', function() {});
```

Just my first guess on this

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that doesn't really change anything. ng-click and the rest works fine. It's only ng-submit that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: and `page:update`? Any luck with that? Just throwing around ideas ;)

Comment: nope. I mean technically that's exactly what `page:load` is supposed to do. So I'm not sure if it's related to that